# Google Map Bug: map mouseout event will be trigger when you hover your mouse on Zoom Panel, Pan Panel, Imagery Panel etc. Any workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Map API v3 fires the mouseout event when you hover your mouse on Zoom Panel, Pan Panel,etc. I think these are part of the map. So, hovering there should not trigger the mouseout event. Here you see this in action,

http://jsfiddle.net/5Zq3T/1/

Any workaround in plain javascript or jquery will be appreciated?
Bug Submitted at [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4146&thanks=4146&ts=1337060244).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  mouseleave instead:

```
$(map.getDiv()).mouseleave(function(){alert('Mouse Out')});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Zq3T/2/

Comment: Thanks. I understand mouseleave. But this is not present in Google V3. mouseleave is the Jquery event. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events. This is definitely a bug in Google V3. Your solution seems to be work for me. Thanks again.

Comment: mouseleave also is a DOM-event(note that the event is used with a DOM-element, not the map-object), so you also could use it with addDomListener. Unfortunately mouseleave still isn't widely supported. But I wouldn't call it a bug, it's the common behaviour that mouseout fires on an element when you hover a child-element of this element.

Comment: If you are not calling this as bug then why mouse outing on polygon or line not trigger this event. They are also child elements man.

Comment: The `mouseout` does what is intended, issue here is that `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are not implemented in Google Maps API and that's a shame. Even if you (@Dr.Molle) mention that this methods are not widely supported, I believe that is not a good reason why not to have it on the API. Google already parses the existent mouse events in their API to make them work across multiple browsers and platforms.